# Custom CSS not working after rolling back on a previous backup

Tags: css, wordpress

Two days ago, I made some custom CSS to fix some things on the layout of the Flatsome theme. Everything was working fine... but then I messed up with my product database, so I had to roll back.

Note: the CSS was a code-snippet (`wpcode`), which is basically stored in a database.

After the rollback, I went and added the same exact code back to code snippets, but it is just not working. I tried everything: cleaning the cache, adding it to the child theme, and adding it to the custom CSS on theme settings.

NOTHING WORKS.

Does anyone have any idea?

I tried rolling back to a previous backup.
Removing and adding the snippets numerous times.
Adding the CSS to the child theme file.
Adding the CSS to the custom CSS is Flatsome's theme settings.
Purging all the cache on LiteSpeed numerous times.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].. You need to show your current state so we have something to look at. Really, this isn't a code question anyway and you'd probably do better at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.